# Extract async function from endpoint code in Node.js

Tags: node.js, async-await, refactoring

In order to reorganize my code, I'm trying to put a portion of code outside the code of my endpoint.

Currently, what is working:

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const userExists = await User.findOne({email: req.body.email})
        if (userExists) {
            return res.status(400).send('User already exists')
        }        
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).send('Internal server error')
    } // stops here if a user does exist into database
    console.log('do next stuff');
...
})
```

And what I'm trying to do is to put this `try/catch` block inside a separated function:

```
async function checkUserExistence(req, res) {
    try {
        const userExists = await User.findOne({email: req.body.email});
        if (userExists) {
            return res.status(400).send('User already exists');
        }        
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).send('Internal server error');
    }
}
```

And then, I simply call the function:

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    checkUserExistence(req, res) // does not stop here if a user does exist into database
    console.log('do next stuff');
...
})
```

Doing that, I still get the response *User already exists* but **the code goes on executing in the calling function**, because the `return res.status(400).send('User already exists')` line only applies to the called function.

How can I solve this issue please ? Thanks for you help.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand the question. Can you please refine the question a little bit?

Comment: I edited my original post adding comments. It should be more clearer. I want the code to stop if a user does exist into the database. And originally it worked. But, when I extract the try/catch block into a separated function, it passes through my function, returns _User already exists_ but does not stop the calling function.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you need to wait for the `Promise` to resolve and the know if `res` has been set.

### Solution 1 - Hacky fun times

```
async function checkUserExistence(req, res) {
    let isExsist = false;
    try {
        const userExists = await User.findOne({email: req.body.email});
        if (userExists) {
           res.status(400).send('User already exists');
           isExsist = true;
        }        
    } catch (error) {
       res.status(500).send('Internal server error');
       isExsist = true;
    }

   return isExsist;
}
```

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    const isExsist = await checkUserExistence(req, res)

    if(isExsist){
       return res;
    }
    console.log('do next stuff');
    ...
})
```

This will work but there are issues with this approach. Mainly the fact that `checkUserExistence` tasks control over `req` and return a `bool` just to acknowledge a thing that `req` already know.

### Solution 2 - Separation of concerns

We can **refactor** the code to be more streamlined and make it have a well defined API.

First, let's remove the `req` and `res` from `checkUserExistence`. No need for them. We now know that `checkUserExistence` should receive `email` and should throw two types of errors (DB errors and USER_ALREADY_EXSIST).

```
async function checkUserExistence(email) {
    const userExists = await User.findOne({ email: email });
    if(userExists) {
        throw new Error('ERROR::USER_ALREADY_EXSIST');
    }
}
```

This function is a part of the `Business Layer`. This means that it **must** stay agnostic to the `Controller Layer`.
The good think about this approach is that you can now use this method without `express`.

Step 2 is to use this `Business Layer` method with the controller.

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {

    try {
      await checkUserExistence(req.body.email);
      res.send("not exist"); // or do stuff

    } catch (e) {
      switch(e.message) {
         case "ERROR::USER_ALREADY_EXSIST": res.status(400).send('User already exists'); brake;
         default:
            res.status(500).send('Internal server error'); brake;
      }
    }
})
```

Now we can see what the HTTP is doing. Note that any Exceptions that are being thrown by the DB will resolve in the `default` case (500).

I would recommend diving into `express` middleware error handling. It can reduce code duplication for general errors. see: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

Comment: I already tried to ```await``` for ```checkUserExistence()``` but I still pass through this function even if a user does exist. If you look at my original question (edited), I still get the execution of ```console.log('do next stuff')``` even if a user exists.

Comment: @Frankie I updated my answer. please check if it fits.

Comment: Why is there ```isExsist = true;``` after the _Internal server error_ message please ?

Comment: What I like inside the Solution 1 is that there is no ```try/catch``` block inside the handler code, that makes the code easier to read.

Comment: Its the hacky part of the solution. Maybe I should of call It `hasError`. or just return an object if an error occurred. Anyway, the idea is to return a value so we can get to the `'do next stuff'` section

Comment: But we don't want the next stuffs to be done if something went wrong with the server, do we ?

Comment: That way you will need to do a check outside the method. This is why I recommend `Solution 2` its leaves `checkUserExistence` to do its thing without warring about  whats comes next.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view in scope of refactoring you need to move business logic outside of controller. Your model related function shouldn't know anything about request or response, you need to feed them only data that they directly requires.

`checkUserExistence` function should only notify you wether user exists or not

```js
function checkUserExistence(body) {
    return User.findOne({email: body.email});
}
```

and controller needs to manage with response

```js
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    let userExists;
    try {
      userExists = await checkUserExistence(req.body)
    } catch (e) {
      return res.status(500).send('Internal server error');
    }
    if (userExists) {
      return res.status(400).send('User already exists');
    } 
})
```

Comment: If I ```return``` the ```checkUserExistence()``` function, the code never goes further the return line.

Comment: hm, I thought that this was what you asked about. Please clarify your expected behaviour

Comment: Maybe you will have a better understanding of what I'm asking now I have edited the original question.

Comment: In my opinion, this modification makes the code even harder to read compared to the original one.